# Android Location Documentation provides links to location-samples in GitHub but these samples do not run with SdkVersion 29

Tags: service, location

Documentation provided by Google/Android for their location services is sketchy and does not allow me to write a program.  Android provides links to code samples in GitHub but these samples do not run with SdkVersion 29.  My understanding is that Android only accepts SdkVersion 29 or higher.  Clearly, some Android designers have code that actually works on their current systems.  How can I get access to an actual code sample for location that works with the latest (or ver 29) Android?

Comment: "but these samples do not run with SdkVersion 29"—what makes you say that? Are you getting errors with them? What do they say? Please read [ask].

Comment: Foolish me;  I believed the android documentation (https://developer.android.com/training/location/permissions) that states that android:foregroundServiceType="location" is required for version 29.  The code sample referenced in the android docs does work in version 29, although it uses depreciated system calls and violates the Android good practices.  It would be nice to have example code that is up to date and works right.